# Is an isentropic process reversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, adiabatic

In one of my books, a process is said to be **isentropic** from which they conclude that it is **adiabatic** thus **reversible**.
I don't think "isentropic" is a sufficient condition for these conclusions. 
Can someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process):

> In thermodynamics, an isentropic process is an idealized thermodynamic process that is adiabatic and in which the work transfers of the system are frictionless; there is no transfer of matter and the process is reversible.

An isentropic process is, *by definition*, adiabatic and reversible.

Comment: I disagree.  What about an irreversible cycle in which the entropy of the working substance (the system) returns to its original value at the end of the cycle?  Of course, in such a situation, the change in entropy of the surroundings is not zero.

Comment: @ChesterMiller "The word 'isentropic' is occasionally, though not customarily, interpreted in another way, reading it as if its meaning were deducible from its etymology. This is contrary to its original and customarily used definition." That's from the second paragraph.  Typically it is _not_ used to mean "no change in entropy" although that is what the name implies.

Comment: Thanks @JMac.  I'm just wondering what the OP had in mind when he asked this.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Oh, I totally got where it was coming from.  Once you get used to the naming convention it just seems reasonable that isentropic should mean what you would think it means; but I kept my answer simple because I think it spoke for itself well given the specific question asked.

Comment: @JMac seems odd to have the term "isentropic" mean something **different** from its mathematical definition of just $\Delta S_\text{system} = 0$. The same way how isothermal means $\Delta T_\text{system} = 0$, isobaric means $\Delta P_\text{system} = 0$, isochoric means $\Delta V_\text{system} = 0$, etc... So it seems Wikipedia is likely confused here --- it's actually the term, "*reversible*" that means $\Delta S_\text{universe} = 0$, while "isentropic" only refers to the system's entropy change. Thus it's possible for an irreversible process with $\Delta S_\text{system} = 0$ to be isentropic

Comment: @ChetMiller Hi Chet. I came upon this while researching isentropic processes. It had been my understanding that for a process (not cycle) to be isentropic it has to be both adiabatic and reversible.  But in a discussion I was told that it need not be either. The example given was an irreversible process that simultaneously transfers heat to the surroundings getting rid of the generated entropy so that the entropy of the system remains constant. Does that make sense to you? Mind you I am not talking about a cycle but a process.

Comment: @BobD A cycle is just an example of a process.  In my judgment, what you were told is correct.

Comment: @ChetMiller But Chet, if a process doesn’t return a system to its initial state how can it be a cycle?

Comment: @BobD I didn't say that.  What I am saying is (a) that a non-adiabatic process on a closed system doesn't have to be reversible  to yield a zero entropy change and (b) an **adiabatic** irreversible process must always yield a positive entropy change.

Comment: @ChetMiller On (a) by "zero entropy change" are you referring to an isentropic process, as in a constant entropy path, or just the change between equilibrium states.

Comment: @BobD I'm referring to the latter, a change between equilibrium states that ends up with zero entropy change.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thank you. Because the person I was discussing this maintained that a non-adiabatic process doesn't have to be reversible for the process to be isentropic which I didn't think was correct.

Comment: @BobD It depends on what you mean by isentropic.  Do you mean constant entropy at every increment in time during the process, or do you mean just for the initial and final states.

Comment: @ChetMiller I thought the definition of isentropic meant constant system entropy at every increment in time. Am I wrong?

Comment: @BobD I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify all of your doubts.
Suppose a system is going through a process from state 1 to state 2. There are two possibilities, the process may be reversible and may be irreversible. 
Let's talk in general, 
$$dS=(\Delta Q/T)+ dS_{gen}$$  so, first doubt whether isentropic process is always reversible,
suppose the system is going from 1 to 2 by irreversible process in the case taken above, so there will be entropy change due to heat exchange and some entropy will be generated. But think about the case when heat is given to the system.
therefore, $\Delta Q/T$ will be negative where as $dS_{gen}$ is positive. So, if $dS_{gen}$ cancels out with $(\Delta Q/T)$, $dS$ will be zero but process is irreversible.
**so always we can't say that isentropic process is reversible process.**
***Continuing the discussion,***
let suppose the above process is reversible, so $dS_{gen}=0$, also if the process is adiabatic, therefore, there is no heat exchange $(\Delta Q/T=0)$.\
This means from our equation dS=0, also 
**Therefore, reversible adiabatic process is always isentropic process.** 
talking about the reverse, 
the first case we discussed, the process was isentropic but not an adiabatic one. 
**so, an isentropic process can not always be declared as an adiabatic process.** 
Hope you have got it.